# How to find the best route

Tags: python, performance, path, routes, logic

So this is a question regarding the iCode competition.

As you can see, the robot figure is what you control.

You can control the robot to step forward and backward and turn left and right.

The point of the level is:

Find the best route for the robot to collect all of the pieces from his spaceship.

In all, you must step a maximum of 114 steps (including turns).

The rugged tiles will decrease the robot's life by 10% and don't die in the process.

Of course, you will need to write code for the final solution, but please can anyone help me find the route first? (How the robot should walk and turn)

I worked a week on this, but my best solution was 120 steps.

Thanks!

The level: 
https://ibb.co/fSPvLHZ

My current route: 
https://ibb.co/JHL9HH3

Code (I plan on shortening it after I figure out the best route; The robot is called Dev):

```
Dev.turnLeft()
Dev.step(5)
Dev.step(-7)
Dev.turnLeft()
Dev.step(-13)
Dev.turnRight()
Dev.step(2)
Dev.turnLeft()
Dev.step(1)
Dev.step(-1)
Dev.turnRight()
Dev.step(11)
Dev.turnLeft()
Dev.step(7)
Dev.turnLeft()
Dev.step(2)
Dev.step(-2)
Dev.turnRight()
Dev.step(4)
Dev.turnLeft()
Dev.step(11)
Dev.turnLeft()
Dev.step(9)
Dev.turnLeft()
Dev.step(7)
Dev.turnLeft()
Dev.step(3)
Dev.turnLeft()
Dev.step(2)
Dev.turnRight()
Dev.step(-1)
Dev.step(1)
Dev.turnLeft()
Dev.step(3)
Dev.turnRight()
Dev.step(5)
Dev.turnRight()
Dev.step(3)
Dev.turnRight()
Dev.step(2)
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Sure, I've edited to show my current route.

Comment: Can't see the edit

Comment: could you also post your code (copy and paste it at the end of your question)? It might allow to comment on it, detect potential issues.

Comment: Hi, I've made all of the edits now